# Where does the order confirmation email function lives?

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I can't find the specific code line where the system sends to the user the order confirmation email.

In which file should I be looking for that function?

Comment: you can see in modules/ps_emailalerts

Answer (score 2):

It sends the email in `classes/PaymentModule.php` on line 764:

https://github.com/PrestaShop/PrestaShop/blob/1.6.0.11/classes/PaymentModule.php#L764-L775

```
Mail::Send(
    (int)$order->id_lang,
    'order_conf',
    Mail::l('Order confirmation', (int)$order->id_lang),
    $data,
    $this->context->customer->email,
    $this->context->customer->firstname.' '.$this->context->customer->lastname,
    null,
    null,
    $file_attachement,
    null, _PS_MAIL_DIR_, false, (int)$order->id_shop
);
```